# Changing color of grid

Tags: color, standalone, grids, overpic

I am using overpic package on a standalone document class. I want to write some text over an image. However, the image I am using is black, therefore, the grid does not seem to be helpful here. How can I change the color of the grid?

Comment: Hey, try: `{\color{red} \begin{overpic}[width=.6\linewidth, grid, tics=10]{example-image} \put(3,27){\color{blue}\huge\LaTeX} \end{overpic}`

Comment: @TVL It worked!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Missing a `}` at the end and I am sure there is a more elegant way, but I'm glad it worked :D